# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: akka/util/Helpers$ConfigOps$

Tags: java, apache-spark, noclassdeffounderror

I am following an article from below link to create a simple spark job in java.

https://www.datasciencebytes.com/bytes/2016/04/18/getting-started-with-spark-running-a-simple-spark-job-in-java/

Below is my Java File:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SparkAppMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("Example Spark App")
                .setMaster("local[*]"); // Delete this line when submitting to a cluster
        JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        JavaRDD<String> stringJavaRDD = sparkContext.textFile("/tmp/nationalparks.csv");
        System.out.println("Number of lines in file = " + stringJavaRDD.count());
    }
}
```

And Below is my POM.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>edu.berkeley</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

i have tried the solution like spark-streaming version should be same as spark-core (1.5.2). Same for spark-streaming-kafka_2.10.

Comment: You trouble seems not related to `Spark` but to akka module only. Here : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka many additionnal aka modules are listed. Maybe one of them complete tour akka-actor one by the classes it misses ?

Answer (score 0):

Added following pom.xml and issue resolved

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>edu.berkeley</groupId>
<artifactId>simple-project</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-json</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```